# JUNIT4 doesn't work under java 8

Tags: java, unit-testing, intellij-idea, junit4

I have some unit-tests for project, which I execute in intellij idea. If I use java 7, tests work fine, but when I change java from 7 to 8, I get this  error stacktrace on all my unit-tests.

```
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException
at com.intellij.junit4.JUnit4IdeaTestRunner.startRunnerWithArgs(JUnit4IdeaTestRunner.java:119)
at com.intellij.junit4.JUnit4IdeaTestRunner.startRunnerWithArgs(JUnit4IdeaTestRunner.java:42)
at com.intellij.rt.execution.junit.JUnitStarter.prepareStreamsAndStart(JUnitStarter.java:234)
at com.intellij.rt.execution.junit.JUnitStarter.main(JUnitStarter.java:74)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
at com.intellij.rt.execution.application.AppMain.main(AppMain.java:144)
```

What is root cause of this problem?

UPDATE - add imports of test class and header.

```
import junit.framework.TestCase;
import mockit.Expectations;
import mockit.NonStrictExpectations;
import mockit.Mocked;

public class PrepareModule extends TestCase {
```

Comment: Looks like the Problem is not in JUNIT it is in intellij

Comment: Add some code please.

Comment: Do you use the latest version of IntelliJ?

Comment: I'm running JUnit 4.12 in IntelliJ 15 right now.

Comment: Yes, I'm using the latest version of Intellij Idea

Comment: Propably, viewing of code is pointless, besause absolutely different tests failures after changing version of java.

Comment: `com.intellij.junit4.JUnit4IdeaTestRunner....` - this is not JUnit per se.

Comment: And [that class](https://github.com/JetBrains/intellij-community/blob/master/plugins/junit_rt/src/com/intellij/junit4/JUnit4IdeaTestRunner.java) doesn't throw an `IllegalArgumentException` (at least not in the current version and the other versions I've checked)

Comment: At least show the HEADER of your JUnit class - which imports and which annotations exactly you are using.

Comment: Another experiment you should do is that: convert your project into a Maven project (https://examples.javacodegeeks.com/enterprise-java/maven/junit-maven-example/), use JUnit as Maven dependency (thus you guarantee you use always the same and the correct version) and then try running it under various versions of Java.

Comment: Update, ok, I will try.

Comment: Well, you are using JUnit4 but in a JUnit3 way! Do NOT extend TestCase, but annotate your test methods with @Test instead. Howto: http://www.asjava.com/junit/junit-3-vs-junit-4-comparison/

Comment: Still get same error

Comment: I had a similar problem with some legacy code, but in Eclipse, and for me the JMockit answer below did the trick.

Answer (score 1):

What version of JMockIt are you using? Some older versions of JMockIt are not compatible with Java 8.

I had almost the same problem as you (everything the same, except my tests weren't extending TestCase). I fixed my problem by upgrading JMockIt 1.0 -> 1.14.

Comment: I had the same problem with some legacy code (but in Eclipse) and that hint solved it for me. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You say you are using **JUnit 4** but your code snippet includes:

```
import junit.framework.TestCase;

public class PrepareModule extends TestCase {
}
```

**This is using the JUnit 3 style of test**

Try it this way:

```
import org.junit.Test;

public class PrepareModule {
    @Test
    public void someTest() {
    }
}
```

Comment: Can you check for JUnit 3 dependencies and remove them? The approach of this answer seems correct.

Answer (score 0):

OK, with fresh eyes looking at your stacktrace:

```
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException
    at com.intellij.junit4.JUnit4IdeaTestRunner.startRunnerWithArgs(JUnit4IdeaTestRunner.java:119)
    at com.intellij.junit4.JUnit4IdeaTestRunner.startRunnerWithArgs(JUnit4IdeaTestRunner.java:42)
    at com.intellij.rt.execution.junit.JUnitStarter.prepareStreamsAndStart(JUnitStarter.java:234)
    at com.intellij.rt.execution.junit.JUnitStarter.main(JUnitStarter.java:74)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at com.intellij.rt.execution.application.AppMain.main(AppMain.java:144)
```

Assuming this is the entire stack, I see packages only from:

- `java.lang`
- `sun.reflect`
- `com.intellij`

This tells me that `JUnit` has nothing to do with the problem; and probably the problem lies in the class at the top (or bottom, whichever) of the stack: `com.intellij.junit4.JUnit4IdeaTestRunner`

Try a different **JUnit Runner** if you can, such as [from command line](http://junit.org/junit4/faq.html#running_4):

```
java org.junit.runner.JUnitCore <test class name>
```

Answer (score 0):

I think this issue is introduced by IDEA.

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. Once you have sufficient [reputation](http://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment](http://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment) on any post. Also check this [what can I do instead](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead).